# What to do with the [aliens] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment the tag [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) is ambiguous, as the tag wiki states itself:

> Generally, indicates the presence of extra-terrestrial beings in a film or television project. Can also specifically refer to the second of the Alien movie series.

I think one tag should not refer to two completely different things, because that way it becomes completely useless as a filter.

In this scenario, it might still work if I am interested in questions about aliens in general, because the second *Alien* movie happens to fall into that category. If I however want to specifically find questions about the movie *Aliens* by James Cameron, I have to dig through all the noise of movies having aliens in them.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

My suggestion would be to drop the general meaning completely, since it's rubbish. In my opinion creating tags for each and every general topic a movie could be about is not a good idea. Therefore [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) should be used for the specific movie [*Aliens*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/) and nothing else. (I have to admit that I think to remember having already enforced this policy on my own behalf in the past, without opening a meta discussion for it. Forgive me if this wasn't in the spirit of the overall community.)

---

But whatever will be decided on the neccessity of a general alien topic-tag (which is the more general and more important question buried within this question), the tag named [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) should still be used for the specific movie instead of naming it differently. Since the general tag would have a larger range of possible names, the movie, which only has a single unique name, should therefore have prevalence over the general topic (another possibility would be [aliens-1986](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens-1986), but this policy should only be used for duplicate movie titles).

Comment: agreed.  using "aliens" for any movie that has aliens is not a good idea, it should only be used for questions concerning the movie "Aliens."

Comment: I think your opinion should be implemented.

Comment: Fair enough, that wouldve been my alternative solution anyway. :)

Comment: I can however think of a few rare cases where a tag for extra-terrestrials in movies would have a valid use case. (for example how their portray has changed over the years etc.) But you are right that we should move the discussion of general topic tags to another meta question.

Comment: I'm good with this.

Comment: "aliens" to mean "movie that contains aliens" is a *terrible* tag anyway - it should mean [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/)

Answer (score -4):

**My suggestion:** Split the tag up.

- [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) for movies that feature extraterrestrial beings
- [alien-2-aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-2-aliens) for the second *Alien* movie

Comment: [tag:alien-2-aliens] sounds weirdo.