# Meaning of revenge tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently the questions about the TV-show [*Revenge*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1837642/) have been retagged [revenge-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge-tv) in order to distinguish it from the general [revenge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge) tag used for movies about revenges.

But given that such general topic tags are actually discouraged, as also seen in [this related discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/952/49) about [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) and its resolution and the fact that [revenge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge) is only used (and seems only valid) on ID questions currently, it would probably be more appropriate to drop the general meaning and use [revenge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revenge) for the TV-show only, as was done with the [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) tag in the related discussion.

What do you think?

Comment: Why [tag:revenge-tv]? why not [tag:revenge-tv-series]

Comment: **A dish best served cold.** is this tag discription for  Revenge  is acceptable?

Comment: @AnkitSharma This would would reserve too much space for an appendage that has only meta usage.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Please create a separate meta post for this. I think that there are some tags that simply use -tv while others use the -tv-series suffix. Standardisation will be good.

Comment: @coleopterist you just stolen words from my tongue. Thinking the same but was busy in pets.se. Will do it soon.

Comment: @coleopterist done http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/what-is-a-good-way-to-tag-a-tv-series i think it need little reward and you are good in it ;)

Comment: @AnkitSharma I hope that you meant rewOrd because that's what I've done. I've also rewArded it with a +1 for good measure :)