# About [zombies] and [vampires]

Tags: discussion, tags

[aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) are already dead. Obviously, [aliens](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens) should be about the classic sci-fi movie and not about aliens. Why are we even talking about aliens? Surely a conversation specifically about aliens would be off topic here? Oh... [that tag has already been removed](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/952/what-to-do-with-the-aliens-tag).

Can we also get rid of the [zombies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies) and [vampires](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampires) tags as well? I suspect that the bulk of these are going to be used where the genre tag [horror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror) is applicable, and the rest of the time they're going to be used on identification questions, rather than just being stated in the body of the question.

Shall we free the world from [zombies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombies) and [vampires](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampires)?

Comment: I thought to bring [tag:robo-zombies] and [tag:techno-vampires] and you want to kill the existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed we should remove those tags, those are general topic tags which don't have any use here, as already explained to some degree in your linked question. Afterall we're not going to introduce tags for each and every possible thing depicted in a movie, [cars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars) is already being misused frequently for that.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of discussion (in the same way as the sex discussion) to vote for this answer would be to say that we should keep these tags for the purpose of questions that relate to zombie or vampire portrayal in movies or TV in general, or to tag ID questions that include them.

Comment: After all, are we not in danger of removing most tags that are not names of movies or TV shows?  Tags are used to make it easier to find content later - doesn't the use of common themes make that better?

Comment: That is indeed a valid concern, I don't think it applies to each and every possible creature or thing depicted in a movie, though. We're not really near to removing all non-movie tags yet.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - but logically we're proposing to remove all theme related tags by going down this route.  Just wanted to make that clear.

Comment: I think all theme tags should go, in lieu of keeping genre tags - genres and themes go hand in hand so we don't need to keep both. I'm not even a fan of genre tags but they're actually useful in the context of ID questions, film technique questions, camera questions, director questions, etc

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are questions **about** this character type that are unrelated or only tangentially related to a specific instance of that being. Provided it's used correctly, I don't see how these tags are inappropriate. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/how-were-zombies-first-depicted-in-film/9909#9909 How else would this be tagged appropriately?

Comment: @iandotkelly *"logically we're proposing to remove all theme related tags"* - Sure, and that's a very good thing.